# Why is List.Sort() so much faster than TreeView.Sort()?

Tags: c#, list, treeview

Example:
I have a list and a tree of 10000 identical elements.

While benchmarking, I get a big difference in sort times:
List.Sort () (-about 60 ms)
TreeView.Sort () (about 3600 ms)

I have specially coded the comparators to be completely identical.

Based on the code below, can anybody explain the difference in timing?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace List
{
class Program
{
    public class comp_list : IComparer<string>
      {
          public int Compare(string xx, string yy) { string x = xx.ToString(); string y = yy.ToString();  return x.CompareTo(y);  } 
      }
    public class comp_tree : IComparer
      {
          public int Compare(object xx, object yy) { string x = xx.ToString(); string y = yy.ToString();  return x.CompareTo(y); }
      }


    static void Main()
    {

        List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
        TreeView tv = new TreeView();

        int Cnt = 10000;
        string s="";
        Random R = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<Cnt; i++) 
          {
            s=(R.Next(0,Cnt)).ToString();
            MyList.Add( s );
            tv.Nodes.Add( s );
          }

        Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();  t.Start();             
        comp_list cmp = new comp_list(); 
        MyList.Sort( cmp );  
        t.Stop();  Console.WriteLine("SORT_LIST={0}",t.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        tv.TreeViewNodeSorter= new comp_tree();
        Stopwatch tt = new Stopwatch();  tt.Start();             
        tv.Sort();   
        tt.Stop();  Console.WriteLine("SORT_TREE={0}",tt.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

But your comparers aren't identical. `comp_list` is an `IComparer<string>`. Its `Compare` method takes `string` arguments, and the `ToString` method just returns the string. It's quite possible that the JIT compiler can replace all calls to `string.ToString` with code that just returns the original reference.

In fact, replacing your `comp_list.Compare` method with:

```
        public int Compare(string xx, string yy)
        {
            return xx.CompareTo(yy);
        }
```

results in no difference in run time.

`comp_tree` is an `IComparer`. The items passed to it are `TreeNode` references. The comparer has to call the `ToString` method on that object, which then has to return the value of the `Text` property.

Simply put, `string.ToString` is much faster than `TreeNode.ToString`.

### More information

Actually, there's more going on than just that. I modified your code a bit to time the comparisons and also count them. It turns out that comparisons do take longer, as I surmised above, but the `TreeView` sort also does approximately twice as many comparisons as the `List` sort does. I suspect that it also spends a lot more time in swapping things. Here's the modified code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace treeviewSort
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class comp_list : IComparer<string>
        {
            public Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            public int CompareCount = 0;
            public int Compare(string xx, string yy)
            {
                ++CompareCount;
                sw.Start();
                string x = xx.ToString();
                string y = yy.ToString();
                sw.Stop();
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }
        }

        public class comp_tree : IComparer
        {
            public Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            public int CompareCount = 0;
            public int Compare(object xx, object yy)
            {
                ++CompareCount;
                sw.Start();
                string x = xx.ToString();
                string y = yy.ToString();
                sw.Stop();
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }
        }


        private static void Main()
        {
            DoThisTwice();
            DoThisTwice();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DoThisTwice()
        {
            List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
            TreeView tv = new TreeView();

            int Cnt = 10000;
            string s = "";
            Random R = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < Cnt; i++)
            {
                s = (R.Next(0, Cnt)).ToString();
                MyList.Add(s);
                tv.Nodes.Add(s);
            }

            Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();
            t.Start();
            comp_list cmp = new comp_list();
            MyList.Sort(cmp);
            t.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("SORT_LIST={0}. Comparisons={1}. Compare time={2}", t.ElapsedMilliseconds, cmp.CompareCount, cmp.sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            var tvcmp = new comp_tree();
            tv.TreeViewNodeSorter = tvcmp;
            Stopwatch tt = new Stopwatch();
            tt.Start();
            tv.Sort();
            tt.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("SORT_TREE={0} Comparisons={1}. Compare time={2}", tt.ElapsedMilliseconds, tvcmp.CompareCount, tvcmp.sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

I run it twice to eliminate any delays that might be caused by JIT-ing the code. The first time through makes sure that everything is compiled, so the next time there aren't any such delays. In this simple code it doesn't seem to make much difference, but in general it's a good idea. Actually, it'd probably be best to run this 100 times or more in a single test, but for our purposes here it's okay to run it just twice.

The results are enlightening:

```
SORT_LIST=20. Comparisons=141289. Compare time=3
SORT_TREE=849 Comparisons=242150. Compare time=25
SORT_LIST=19. Comparisons=141090. Compare time=3
SORT_TREE=850 Comparisons=241987. Compare time=25
```

Looking at the [source code for TreeView.Sort](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView.cs,4bdde3ab578acbf8) gives more insight. Basically what happens is that the `Sorted` flag is set, and [RefreshNodes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView.cs,d9b0d33f57983858) is called. That method copies all of the nodes from the `Nodes` collection into an array. Then the `Nodes` collection is cleared and `AddRange` is called to add the nodes back to the `Nodes` array. The work is done in the [AddInternal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeNodeCollection.cs,a0a096fb99e95e6e) method.

So, whereas `List.Sort` sorts the items in place, `TreeView.Sort` builds an empty list of nodes and then inserts the nodes one at a time into the new list. That's why it takes so much longer.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `comp_tree` class shouldn't call the `.ToString()` but cast to `TreeNode` and use its `Text` property.

```
public class comp_tree : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object xx, object yy)
    {
        string x = ((TreeNode)xx).Text;
        string y = ((TreeNode)yy).Text;
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

The `comp_tree.Compare()` is called more often than `comp_list.Compare()`.

**comp_tree**: 242042
**comp_list**: 144447

So, I had to dig into the `TreeView.Sort` code to find the issue.
This code for sure isn't meant to be high performant. It first clears all TreeNodes from the TreeView and adds one after another again sorted. That takes time.

The `List(T).Sort()` algorithm uses insertion sort, Heapsort, or Quicksort. Highly optimized of course. For more information see Remarks section of [List.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `TreeView.Sort` algorithm uses some kind of the Insertion sort, but not even slightly optimized. So much slower of course.

Answer (score 0):

In this structure the items are sequentially allocated in memory, after sorting they must "find its place" in memory, next to the previous one, on the other hand Lists items only have references to the next elements but they are not sequentially ordered in memory.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer i have this:

## Jim Mischel   source code:

```
SORT_LIST=84. Comparisons=178337. Compare time=20
SORT_TREE=3283 Comparisons=242048. Compare time=123
SORT_LIST=79. Comparisons=173581. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3282 Comparisons=242100. Compare time=121

SORT_LIST=81. Comparisons=174326. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3013 Comparisons=242095. Compare time=119
SORT_LIST=76. Comparisons=172590. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3075 Comparisons=241952. Compare time=125

SORT_LIST=82. Comparisons=173555. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=4012 Comparisons=242104. Compare time=121
SORT_LIST=82. Comparisons=171671. Compare time=22
SORT_TREE=3987 Comparisons=242045. Compare time=136
```

## Andy source correction:

```
This variant with
public class comp_tree : IComparer
{
public Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
public int CompareCount = 0;
public int Compare(object xx, object yy)
{
    ++CompareCount;
    sw.Start();
    string x = ((TreeNode)xx).Text;
    string y = ((TreeNode)yy).Text;
    sw.Stop();
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
}


SORT_LIST=82. Comparisons=176456. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3263 Comparisons=242053. Compare time=36
SORT_LIST=79. Comparisons=181171. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3094 Comparisons=241980. Compare time=36

SORT_LIST=84. Comparisons=179307. Compare time=20
SORT_TREE=3064 Comparisons=242165. Compare time=37
SORT_LIST=77. Comparisons=173915. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3313 Comparisons=242022. Compare time=36

SORT_LIST=87. Comparisons=186245. Compare time=21
SORT_TREE=3214 Comparisons=241970. Compare time=37
SORT_LIST=78. Comparisons=176906. Compare time=19
SORT_TREE=3349 Comparisons=242058. Compare time=36
```

And If treeview contain 100000 elem, then .Sort i can't wait !!!!

Comment: But will your TreeView contain 100000 items at the top level? That would be rather unusual. Things are much different if the TreeView has 100000 elements total, but in several levels. Insertion is much quicker then, because the number of items that must be moved during each insertion is smaller.